How to recover deleted API from AWS API Gateway?
I accidentally deleted one of REST API from API Gateway.  Is there a way to restore it by myself or AWS support can help it?
If I have to recreate the API, is there a way to keep the same API ID, so that I don't have to change all settings in other places?
Please advise.  Thank you.
Regards,
Joey
I can find "DeleteRestApi" in event history of Cloud Trail.  But not sure what to do next.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUCl9w_SOuRx2a1u51TFG-Xg/recovering-deleted-api-from-api-gateway
This source is saying to contact support.
